# Why can't I find any keyframes for location in the Blender animation window?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I've noticed that when I'm editing the dopesheet in the animation window of blender that I can't find any keyframes representing the location of my model and I'm trying to remove them so I can restart an animation(they basically float up and down) but I really cannot seem to find where the keyframes for the z location of the model are.

I was hoping to duplicate and drag them so it would be a smoother animation but again, I can't find any keyframes of this. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it turns out that I had to zoom right out to see those keyframes XD So if you're having the same issue, scroll with your mouse wheel to zoom right out and you should see the keyframes for the model's location and be able to edit them from there :)

Comment: You might want to try and use the Home key, to zoom everything into view..

Comment: Or press A (to select all) and then press numpad . (period)